# Is there a way to `\kill` a row in {tabular}

Tags: tables

Is there a way to `\kill` a row in a {tabular} or {array} environment? I want to provide text that will set the column widths but then have that row not appear.

Comment: You can set column widths by using options like `p{<width>}` for `tabular` or `array`. Another way is to use `\hphantom{<content>}` for cells in a particular row. This will make cells occupy widths same as `<content>` (but not height) while keeping `<content>` invisible.

Comment: if you could instead use a `tabbing` environment, you've got that option.  if you don't really need a captioned unit, or a float, `tabbing` might give you mire flexibility.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I can't use tabbing -- too much else going on.

Comment: @KevinC I don't like `p{width}` because I want the text centered. I thought of using `\hphantom{<content>}` but then it would _add_ the width of `<content>` to what's already in the cell, but I want to _replace_ the width of the cell with the phantom.

Comment: You can use `\centering` to centre text in a `p`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`longtable` has essentially the same functionality as `tabular`, but also has the `\kill` functionality and adds the capability to break across page boundaries.

If you want to use `\kill` but don't want the table to break at a page boundary, simply put it inside a `table` environment or other box that won't break across pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|l|c|c|} % vertical rules for illustrative purposes only
  very long content & setting the widths & of each column \kill
  actual & content & is short \\
  killed & row & discarded
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize `longtable` had that feature. Thanks. This seems like the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a manual way to achieve what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
  \hline
  Something very & long and & written in a \texttt{tabular} \\
  ABC & DEF & GHI \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
  \hline
  \phantom{Something very} & \phantom{long and} & \phantom{written in a \texttt{tabular}} \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
  ABC & DEF & GHI \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

A "vertical back skip" using `\\[-\normalbaselineskip]` effectively "kills" the row. You may also consider using only `\hphantom`, depending on the content you want to align.

Comment: I like this solution too but I think using `longtable` is a bit cleaner.